# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1, react-native

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native

I am trying to build an archive of my iOS app, but the following linker error occurs:

`Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I have several Pod and react-native dependencies. and am able to build the app for running on both a simulator and a physical device.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try taking a look at some of these suggestions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33536032/apple-mach-o-linker-command-failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed then re-added some of the 3rd party React Native dependencies to the project and linked libraries also and now it builds.

Answer (score 0):

In case, if anyone is having this issue during archiving only, go to `project > pod > targets`. You will see `React` in the list, delete the `React`, clean the project, and then try archiving. Hope it will work. Most of the times it happens during archiving and throws warning of `duplicate`. By deleting the `React` from the `pod` fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Delete **node_modules** folder and **yarn.lock** file

`npm install` Or `yarn install`

run

```
react-native link
```

finally run

```
react-native run-ios
```

this worked for me.

Hope so it will help someone